# Protect html/css/js on Android asesst folder

Tags: android

I working an Android application. Some activities, I used webview and load html from Android asesst folder. On apk if rename package to name.apk.zip then anyone can easily access my asesst folder content.
Now I want to protect my assect content mainly html files.

Please help to give some suggest about html encryption or Android studio plugins about protection.

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient way to do this, it's include that files in your Server, and getting files by authorization.

To do it locally. I suggest to create custom task in gradle for mapping your html/css files in some incode storage, with `Base64` (encoding just for ex.). It's looks like:

```
task mapAssets(dependsOn: build) {
    SOURCE_FILE = 'Path to Source File'
    doFirst {
        println "I'm Gradle"
    }
    String source = new File(SOURCE_FILE).text

    ENCODED_FILE = 'Path to Encoded File'
    new File(ENCODED_FILE).withWriter { out ->
         out.println source.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
    }
}
```

Later in your `Java` code, just find `ENCODED_FILE` and make call with reading file and mapping again in `HTML`, from `Base64` (or any other encoding).